# javascript how to access the value of an arrays object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am working on a javascript program that uses an array of objects. It uses 3 user input fields for the objects properties. I am stuck on how to access and display the the arrays object and its properties. I want it to save the user input in the array and allow me to display the name in a list and acess the grade so I can do mathematical problems with input vales. I am stuck on how to access arrays objects properties. I used and need to keep the object constructor. This is what I have so far

```
<br>
<p><b>Student Name:</b></p>
<input id="inp" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<p><b>Grade:</b></p>
<input id="inps" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<p><b>Student ID:</b></p>
<input id="inpsid" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="enter()">Enter</button>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="construct()">Constructor</button>
<p>Student Names List:</p>
<p id="iop"></p>
<br>
<p id="opo"></p>
<br>
<p id="cop"></p>
<br>
<script>
var studentArr = [];

  function Student(name, grade, id) {
  this.name = name;
  this.grade = grade;
  this.id = id; 
}

    function enter() {

        var namip = document.getElementById("inp").value;
        var gradip = document.getElementById("inps").value;
        var idip = document.getElementById("inpsid").value;

        var nwStudent = new Student(namip, gradip, idip);

        studentArr.push(nwStudent);

        document.getElementById("cop").innerHTML = "Student Name: " + nwStudent;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: `studentArr[index].property` or `studdentArr[index]['property']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gerardo said:

```
studentArr[index].property or studdentArr[index]['property']
```

It doesn't matter if the object is type JSON object or Array object, just use the syntax.

```
document.getElementById("cop").innerHTML = "Student Name: " + nwStudent['name'];
```

or

```
document.getElementById("cop").innerHTML = "Student Name: " + nwStudent.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a property from an object using dot notation the same way you do with elements (such as when you get a textbox's value). If you want to show the name of your constructed object, use `.name` like so:

```
document.getElementById("cop").innerHTML = "Student Name: " + nwStudent.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you are trying to access the properties of the objects that are in the array.

that would be, for instance, `studentArr[0].name` to get the first student's name.

see here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties for more information.